# Expected value with a kronecker product and Gaussian distributional assumption

Tags: random-matrices, st.statistics, probability-distributions, pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

What is the expected value, $ \mathbb{E}\left[ I \otimes \left( \operatorname{diag}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T\right)\right]$ where $Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2I) $? The kronecker product is where the confusion is setting in.

Comment: $I \otimes B$ is just a block diagonal matrix with diagonal blocks equal to $B$. So $\mathbb{E}[I \otimes B] = I \otimes \mathbb{E}[B]$.

Comment: Can you go further and continue with the part involving $Z's$, which you refer to indirectly as $B$? I ask because I believe $ZZ^T$ may be Wishart distributed given the Gaussian assumptions. I'd like to see the extent to which one might compute the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears straightforward....?
From Steve's comment,
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{diag}(\bf{ZZ}^T)\bf{1}-ZZ^T]=\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{diag}(\bf{ZZ}^T)\bf{1}]-\mathbb{E}[ZZ^T]=0.$$

There must be some typos in the statement of this problem.